# Rating Uwp Application-Displaying Unknown User on store

Tags: uwp, store, rating

I have rated ,submited a feedback for an Uwp application to Microsoft store through the below line of code..

```
[private async Task PromptUserToRateApp()
{
StoreContext _storeContext;
IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync();
        User firstUser = users\[0\];
       _storeContext = StoreContext.GetForUser(firstUser);

StoreRateAndReviewResult result = await _storeContext.RequestRateAndReviewAppAsync();
}][1]
```

Then I opened the app on the store to see the rating.
It is displaying User=‘Unknown’ on the store with all the reviews which I have submitted.

How can we get the username instead of Unknown while rating the application through the above code???
[image: Rating-Store Image]

Comment: I found the same problem in the test, you can choose to let the user jump to the Microsoft Store and then apply the review.

Comment: We can choose to let the user jump to the Microsoft Store But can it be possible to rate the app without redirecting the user to store.

Comment: Hi, I will respond to this question to Microsoft through the channel.

Comment: What is your target OS Version? Please make sure that you have sign-in the Store application when you test your app. Actually I have tested your application in 4 computers whose OS Verison are 1903, I found that if the current windows local user is a domain-joined account, then it will work fine. But if the current windows local user is not a domain-joined account, it will not work just as what you have described, so what's type of your current windows local user account? I am still investigating this issue, once there is any update, I will post it here.

Comment: I have tested it in windows 10 OS Version 1903.It was not joined to domain account.I have signed into store with my personal outlook id.
If we direct the user to store then it displays local user name instead of "unknown".Can it be possible to rate the app without redirecting the user to store.

Comment: Based on my investigation result, if the current local user is the domain-joined account, you can rate the app without redirecting the use to store. Otherwise, you have to redirect the user to the store. I will recommend you report this issue in Windows 10 Feedback hub app to see if there is any workaround for this issue.